# Convert "ção" and other portuguese characters into proper characters

Tags: php

The following code is returning:

```
pontuaÃ§Ã£o
```

I'd like it to return:

```
pontuação
```

Code:

```
$msg = texto("pontuação");
echo $msg;

function texto($string){
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1');
}
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: What encoding is your source file, and what encoding is your web page?

Comment: what happens if you just run `echo "pontuação";` ?

Comment: @eggmatters I get it right. However, "Rácio" becomes "R�cio"